# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Sporadically Spontaneously Reboots on Custom Built Machine

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-failure, gnome3

Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Sporadically Spontaneously Reboots on Custom Built Machine

What happens...

I will be working along and the computer goes through a spontaneous reboot. Usually the reboot is without warning, but sometime there are clues that is it coming like a frozen keyboard or the mouse not acting correctly.

What I have done...

- Verified operating system and all software is up to date. (The OS is regularly updated automatically.)
- Updated motherboard firmware.
- Ran Memtest86 over the weekend to test RAM without error.
- Ran Primes95 overnight to stress test the CPU. No problems.
- Swapped out drive. Same issue even with clean install of the operating system.
- The hardware has all been reseated.
- I did discover that the CPU was running hot (70℃) and increased the cooling. Manufactor specs say 61℃ tops.
- Tried. Tried to read various logs in the /var/log. (I you would like to see them, I will be glad to post recent one with crash and reboot times.

Tidbits that may be "red herring" or may be clues...

- My other Gnome Ubuntu machines (with different hardware specs) built with the same software profile are NOT having the same problem.
- The first time I saw these reboots, it was when I was using ScreenConnect with depends on Java
- Since then I have seen it happen when I am browsing using FireFox
- I have seen it occasionally when I am using LibreOffice
- The other night it rebooted itself when the only thing running was Backup
- After it goes through the crash and reboot cycle and logging back in, trying to use Super Key + "Type to search" to find an application is almost a guarantee to create another crash and reboot. It will usually crash and reboot when the second letter is typed.
- Sometime it will automatically reboot again during the reboot after the initial crash and reboot. The reason I know this is because I have to enter disk encryption password again.
- Sometime one of the monitors does not start after the reboot. If the computer is shutdown when this is happening, sometimes the monitor is not turned off either.
- After a cold start - where the machine has been shut off for the night - it will usually behave itself for a couple of hours.
- Frequency of crash is increasing.

Here are the hardware components...

- CORSAIR RM Series RM650 650W ATX12V v2.31 and EPS 2.92 80 PLUS GOLD Certified Full Modular Active PFC Power Supply
- ASUS M5A97 LE AM3+ AMD 970 + SB950 6 X SATA 6
- G.SKILL Sniper Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1866 (PC3 14900) Desktop Memory Model F3-1866C9D-16GSR
- AMD FX-8370 Vishera 8-Core 4.0GHz (4.3GHz Turbo) Socket AM3+ 125W FD8370FRHKBOX Desktop Processor
- Corsair Hydro Series H55 Quiet Edition Liquid CPU Cooler (CW-9060010-WW)
- Cooler Master Rifle Bearing 80mm Silent Cooling Fan
- SAMSUNG 840 EVO MZ-7TE250BW 2.5" 250GB SATA 6Gb/s 1x nm Samsung Toggle DDR 2.0 3-Bit MLC NAND Flash Memory (400Mbps) Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)
- AMD FirePro W4100 100-505817 2 GB 128-bit
- Cable Matters Gold Plated Mini DisplayPort to HDMI
- Dual ASUS PB287Q 4k UHD LED Monitor
- CODE 104-Key Mechanical Keyboard - Cherry MX Brown
- Logitech Wireless Marathon Mouse M705
- Logitech T650 Rechargeable Touchpad with Windows 8 Multi-Touch Navigation
- Penguin USB Bluetooth 4.0 Micro Adapter
- Penguin Wireless N PCI Card v5
- Plantronics BT300 USB Bluetooth Adapter Dongle 85117-02 PL-BT300
- Plantronics Voyager HD Headset

Here is the software list...

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS
- Dia
- Dropbox
- Flash Player Browser Plugin
- FreeFileSync
- IcedTea Plugin
- Inkscape
- Java Run Time
- Keepass
- Linphone
- Mono - mono-complete
- Mount NFS Shares - nfs-kernel-server
- PDF Printer (with an adjust outputed folder and apt-armor)
- rDeskTop
- SimpleScreenRecorder
- SpeedCrunch
- Thunderbird
- VirtualBox
- Wide Margins Bible
- Windows Manager - wmctrl
- FireFox Tweaks...

  - KeeFox
  - AdBlock Plus
  - BetterPrivacy
  - Blur
  - Clean Links
  - Cleanest Addon Manager
  - DownThemAll
  - Element Hiding Helper for AdBlock Plus
  - FoxyProxy Standard
  - ScrapBook X
  - Self-Destructing Cookies
  - Session Manager
  - Snap Links Plus

Links I have read without finding the solution...

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/202335/how-can-i-track-the-cause-of-random-reboots
- https://serverfault.com/questions/386985/how-to-investigate-unexpected-linux-server-shut-down
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown
- [How to diagnose a spontaneous reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/129125/how-to-diagnose-a-spontaneous-reboot)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2094859
- [LInux: How do I diagnose / isolate what's causing "random" hangs and spontaneous reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/106006/linux-how-do-i-diagnose-isolate-whats-causing-random-hangs-and-spontaneous)
- [Computer sponteously reboots when doing heavy file copy to/from disk](https://superuser.com/questions/357878/computer-sponteously-reboots-when-doing-heavy-file-copy-to-from-disk)

Is there other testing or things to look narrow down the problem before just swapping out hardware? If there is not, what hardware would you recommend starting with?

Answer (score 1):

The executive answer: Bad grounding in office electrical system.

After systematically changing out ALL the hardware and still having the same problem, I started to get suspicious of something upstream in the electrical network. Tracked it down a missing ground connection. Fixed that, put all my parts together, and now have two working computers. And a busted budget.